# Is it safe to add or remove null bytes at the end of a file?

Tags: python, file, python-2.7

Is it *always* safe to remove trailing zero or null bytes from the end of a file? I'm worried this might corrupt a file that uses say UTF-16 encoding, or for some other reason.

And further, is it *always* safe to add trailing zero bytes to the end of a file?

As an example using Python I'd do this by stripping single bytes from the file's end until all zero bytes are removed:

```
with open('in.ext', 'rb') as file_in:
    with open('out.ext', 'wb') as file_out:
        data = file_in.read()
        while data.endswith('\x00'):
            data = data[:-1]
        file_out.write(data)
```

This is for the purpose of storing and retrieving arbitrary files on a portable storage medium. I was hoping to get away with padding half written byte blocks  (a block contains 16 bytes) with zero bytes and then simply stripping the bytes off when reading the data back.

Comment: What file encodings do you aim to support? Only UTF8/UTF16?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the application writing and reading the files. Unless you know the exact format of the file, no modification is safe by default. If you know the format, it will be obvious if trailing 0s are needed or not.

After the question edit: "storing and retrieving arbitrary files" is by default incompatible with just randomly stripping bytes. It doesn't matter what the bytes are, you need to preserve the files as they were. If you need proper padding scheme, have a look at stuff used in encryption algorithms - for example [PKCS7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_%28cryptography%29#PKCS7).

Comment: Thanks, PKCS7 looks clever. I ended up just prepending the file length (in a known number of bytes) to the start of the file so that end of file padding is irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on what will use this file after then. Some software may require to find those null bytes at the end, for example if there are used for padding.

In the case of UTF-16, the number of bytes should be even, so you should manage them by pairs (looking for \x00\x00 instead of just \x00).